# Why I can not use FXML with Controllers and fxid in controller?

Tags: javafx

I found [here](https://github.com/goranvasic/JavaFxTutorials/tree/master/JavaFxCommunicationBetweenControllers) what I need. I need access from 1 Controller to another.

But I have a question. Why when I use FXML annotaion I get exception?

I want to make

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML Tab1Controller tab1Controller;
    @FXML Tab2Controller tab2Controller;

    @FXML Tab tab1;   //THIS
    @FXML Tab tab2;   // And this call exception. But if i comment both fields is evertying OK.


    @FXML public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Application started");
        tab1Controller.init(this);
        tab2Controller.init(this);
    }

    public String loadLblTextFromTab1() {
        return tab1Controller.lbl1.getText();
    }

    public void setTab2LabelText(String text) {
        tab2Controller.lbl2.setText(text);
    }
}
```

P.S add the XML file where I have that fx:id

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="299.0" prefWidth="309.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MainController">
   <children>
      <TabPane prefHeight="299.0" prefWidth="309.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Tab 1">
               <content>
                  <fx:include fx:id="tab1" source="tab/Tab1.fxml" />
               </content></Tab>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Tab 2">
               <content>
                  <fx:include fx:id="tab2" source="tab/Tab2.fxml" />
               </content></Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

PSS.

If I use my FXML and Class like this I will get NullPointerException because of `tab1Controller == null`

```
 public class MainController {
    @FXML Tab tab1;
    @FXML Tab1Controller tab1Controller;

    @FXML public void initialize() {
        tab1Controller.init(this); // Line 15
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="controller.MainController">
    <TabPane>
        <Tab fx:id="tab1" closable="false" text="Tab 1">
            <fx:include source="tab/Tab1.fxml"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

Exception looks like

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:15)
    ... 27 more
```

So, now I can not understand why I get that exception? Anyway I generated my `Tab` from fxml file itself.

Comment: Post (at least) the FXML file, and the complete stack trace. Identify which line in the code is throwing the exception.

Comment: I provided all files with link in my question. Anyway here is Exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.Tab field controller.MainController.tab1 to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane`

Comment: You should post that complete stack trace in the question (format it as code). Anyway; it is fairly self-explanatory, no? The `<fx:include>` generates an `AnchorPane` and you are trying to assign it to a `Tab`.

Comment: Consider to use the fx:root construct. It leads to much cleaner code, IMHO. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm

Comment: In the second version, `tab1Controller` won’t be initialized because the `tab1` `fx:id` is not applied to a `<fx:include>`. Why don’t you try it like I did in the answer?

Comment: I have tried and updated version is looks like your answer except 'fx:id="tab1Content"' which I do not call

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  Can not set javafx.scene.control.Tab field controller.MainController.tab1 to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
```

explains what the problem is. The `<fx:include>` generates an `AnchorPane` (presumably that is the root element of `Tab1.fxml`), and you are trying to use a field of type `Tab` to reference it.

If you only need access to the content of the tab, just change the type of the field accordingly:

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML Tab1Controller tab1Controller;
    @FXML Tab2Controller tab2Controller;

    @FXML AnchorPane tab1;   
    @FXML AnchorPane tab2;   


    @FXML public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Application started");
        tab1Controller.init(this);
        tab2Controller.init(this);
    }

    public String loadLblTextFromTab1() {
        return tab1Controller.lbl1.getText();
    }

    public void setTab2LabelText(String text) {
        tab2Controller.lbl2.setText(text);
    }
}
```

If you specifically need access to the tabs themselves, then you'll need `fx:id`s on the `Tab`. As before, to get a reference to the controller, you need an `fx:id` on the `<fx:include>`. So if you want an actual reference to the `Tab` as well as to the controller, you will need (different) `fx:id`s on both the `Tab` and the `<fx:include>`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="299.0" prefWidth="309.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MainController">
   <children>
      <TabPane prefHeight="299.0" prefWidth="309.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="tab1" closable="false" text="Tab 1">
               <content>
                  <fx:include fx:id="tab1Content" source="tab/Tab1.fxml" />
               </content></Tab>
          <Tab fx:id="tab2" closable="false" text="Tab 2">
               <content>
                  <fx:include fx:id="tab2Content" source="tab/Tab2.fxml" />
               </content></Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML Tab1Controller tab1ContentController;
    @FXML Tab2Controller tab2ContentController;

    @FXML Tab tab1;   
    @FXML Tab tab2;   


    @FXML public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Application started");
        tab1Controller.init(this);
        tab2Controller.init(this);
    }

    public String loadLblTextFromTab1() {
        return tab1ContentController.lbl1.getText();
    }

    public void setTab2LabelText(String text) {
        tab2ContentController.lbl2.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should I change my objects to '@FXML AnchorPane tab1; ' ? I have 'Tab' inside 'AnchorPane' but not 'AnchorPane's inside 'Tab'. It was not clear for me

Comment: @Dred The `fx:id` attribute is defined on the `<fx:include>` element, which creates an `AnchorPane`, not a `Tab`.

Comment: @Dred Also, since the `<fx:include>` creates an `AnchorPane`, you actually do have an `AnchorPane` inside each `Tab`.

Comment: Why I can not use `@FXML Tab1Controller tab2ContentController; @FXML Tab tab2;`  intime? I have NPE on  `tab2Controller.init(this);` because `tab2ContentController==null` but `tab1ContentController` is filled

Comment: @Dred I don’t understand that comment.